# Unable to install RPM package on Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, rpm

I am trying to install rpm on Mac 10.10 using this command

```
brew install rpm
```

However, it failed and I got this error. Please guide me how can I fix this?

```
==> Installing rpm dependency: rpm2cpio
==> Downloading http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/archivers/rpm2cpio/files/rpm2cpio?revision=259745&view=co

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Error: Failed to download resource "rpm2cpio"
Download failed: http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/archivers/rpm2cpio/files/rpm2cpio?revision=259745&view=co
```

Comment: Can you pull up that URL in your browser? It works here.

Comment: No I can't. Seems to be blocked by my firewall. Is there a way to ignore firewall?

Comment: Depends on many things all specific to your local network. Talk to your network admin.

Comment: I created the virtual box and tested there what I needed to try

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

brew install rpm2cpio

brew install rpm

rpm2cpio rpm_name.rpm | cpio -idmv